How can I create a day number variable in Stata based on dates?
I want to create a variable with the number of the day a participant took a survey (first day, second day, thirds day, etc.) The issue is that there are participants that took the survey after midnight. For example, this is what it looks like:
Id  date
1   08/03/2020 08:17
1   08/03/2020 12:01
1   08/04/2020 15:08
1   08/04/2020 22:16
2   07/03/2020 08:10
2   07/03/2020 12:03
2   07/04/2020 15:07
2   07/05/2020 00:16
3   08/22/2020 09:17
3   08/23/2020 11:04
3   08/24/2020 00:01
4   10/03/2020 08:37
4   10/03/2020 11:13
4   10/04/2020 15:20
4   10/04/2020 23:05

This is what I want:
Id  date    day
1   08/03/2020 08:17    1
1   08/03/2020 12:01    1
1   08/04/2020 15:08    2
1   08/04/2020 22:16    2
2   07/03/2020 08:10    1
2   07/03/2020 12:03    1
2   07/04/2020 15:07    2
2   07/05/2020 00:16    2
3   08/22/2020 09:17    1
3   08/23/2020 11:04    2
3   08/24/2020 00:01    2
4   10/03/2020 08:37    1
4   10/03/2020 11:13    1
4   10/04/2020 15:20    2
4   10/04/2020 23:05    2

How can I create the day variable taking into consideration participants that who took the survey after midnight still belong to the previous day?

Ambiguities in the question. No attempt at code.

This is an unacknowledged variant of How can I create a day number variable in R based on dates?
There isn't a proper data example here: see the stata tag wiki. So it's ambiguous whether your date variable -- really a datetime variable -- is a string variable or a formatted numeric variable.
There isn't a precise definition of how much after midnight is allowed. All times except midnight are after midnight!
Here the criterion is that up to 120 minutes is allowed. Change according to your precise criterion.
Here the code goes all the way from a presumed initial datetime string to working with mod(,) and the principle that Stata uses millisecond resolution for its datetimes, but yours have resolution of minutes.
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input byte id str16 sdate
1 "08/03/2020 08:17"
1 "08/03/2020 12:01"
1 "08/04/2020 15:08"
1 "08/04/2020 22:16"
2 "07/03/2020 08:10"
2 "07/03/2020 12:03"
2 "07/04/2020 15:07"
2 "07/05/2020 00:16"
3 "08/22/2020 09:17"
3 "08/23/2020 11:04"
3 "08/24/2020 00:01"
4 "10/03/2020 08:37"
4 "10/03/2020 11:13"
4 "10/04/2020 15:20"
4 "10/04/2020 23:05"
end

gen double datetime = clock(sdate, "MDY hm")
gen ddate = dofc(datetime)
format date %tc 
format ddate %td 

gen min_after_mid = mod(datetime, 24 * 60 * 60000)/60000

bysort id : gen wanted = cond(min_after_mid <= 120, ddate - ddate[1], ddate - ddate[1] + 1)  

list, sepby(id)


     +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | id              sdate             datetime       ddate   min_af~d   wanted |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |  1   08/03/2020 08:17   03aug2020 08:17:00   03aug2020        497        1 |
  2. |  1   08/03/2020 12:01   03aug2020 12:01:00   03aug2020        721        1 |
  3. |  1   08/04/2020 15:08   04aug2020 15:08:00   04aug2020        908        2 |
  4. |  1   08/04/2020 22:16   04aug2020 22:16:00   04aug2020       1336        2 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  5. |  2   07/03/2020 08:10   03jul2020 08:10:00   03jul2020        490        1 |
  6. |  2   07/03/2020 12:03   03jul2020 12:03:00   03jul2020        723        1 |
  7. |  2   07/04/2020 15:07   04jul2020 15:07:00   04jul2020        907        2 |
  8. |  2   07/05/2020 00:16   05jul2020 00:16:00   05jul2020         16        2 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  9. |  3   08/22/2020 09:17   22aug2020 09:17:00   22aug2020        557        1 |
 10. |  3   08/23/2020 11:04   23aug2020 11:04:00   23aug2020        664        2 |
 11. |  3   08/24/2020 00:01   24aug2020 00:01:00   24aug2020          1        2 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 12. |  4   10/03/2020 08:37   03oct2020 08:37:00   03oct2020        517        1 |
 13. |  4   10/03/2020 11:13   03oct2020 11:13:00   03oct2020        673        1 |
 14. |  4   10/04/2020 15:20   04oct2020 15:20:00   04oct2020        920        2 |
 15. |  4   10/04/2020 23:05   04oct2020 23:05:00   04oct2020       1385        2 |
     +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

